# Checking for specific email addresses using data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How would I check on registration that a user types in a specific email address?  For example, i want my registration form to only allow these email addresses:

- @gmail.com
- @yahoo.com
- @live.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
[RegularExpression( @"@(gmail|yahoo|live)\.com$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid domain in email address. The domain must be gmail.com, yahoo.com or live.com")]
public string EmailAddress { get ; set ; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a regular expression; you can just use the split() function to obtain the part of the email address after the "@" and check it against your list of allowed providers.

This by itself doesn't guarantee that it's a well-formed email address (that may require a regex, and a somewhat complicated one), but it will make sure that the address ends with one of the domains on your list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RegularExpressionValidator control and an expression to look for the email domains. You can find a sample at http://www.regexplib.com if you don't already have one.

You're probably going to want a CustomValidator as well that performs an identical server-side check. Users can circumvent your RegularExpressionValidator if they disable Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is not built in but you can use `[RegularExpression]`.You can write custom `EmailAttribute` deriving from `RegularExpressionAttribute`.

A very well implementation is done [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx)

You can use following regular expression to check email:

> ^[a-z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)*\.([a-z]{2,4})$

Beside this, you can have [Data Annotation Extension](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Email/Create) which has `[Email]` attribute that allows for validating an email address.